# Trying to limit a TextField from material-ui and receiving inputRef error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm currently trying to limit an autocomplete textfield in my project, but whenever I use `InputProps={{ maxLength: 2 }}`, it spits out an error saying that my `inputRef.current is null`, but i've set the ref in `inputRef` prop using `React.createRef();` it stil giving me an error and by `console.log(inputRef)` it actually show me the right element that ref is being set to.

I'm using this to create and this function to just focus the element whenever i Click it

```
const inputRef = React.createRef();

  const focusOnClick = () => {
    inputRef.current.focus();
  };
```

This is the component where the Autocomplete is at.

```
<Uf
   id="Uf"
   name="uf"
   label="UF"
   value="SP"
   onClick={focusOnClick}
   inputRef={inputRef}
   inputProps={{ maxLength: 2 }}
   fullWidth
/>
```

And this is the autocomplete, `{...importedProps}` is where all the Props that are being passed though the first component to here

```
<Autocomplete
      options={ufList}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label}
      style={{ width: 200, marginLeft: 10 }}
      onChange={changeValue}
      getOptionSelected={(option) => option.value === value}
      className={clsx(classes.TextField, classes.dense)}
      // value={value}
      autoHighlight
      autoSelect
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          {...importedProps}
          error={Boolean(errorMessage)}
          helperText={errorMessage}
          label="UF"
          value={value}
          margin="dense"
          variant="outlined"
        />
      )}
    />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To focus on your `TextField` you just have to use property `autoFocus`, don't have to use `onClick` for it.
2. If you still want to do it `onClick` try using the [useRef hook instead](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref).
3. I'm pretty sure you ran into an error because you tried using `inputRef={inputRef}` in your `<Uf/>` component that's not a Material-UI component. If you want to focus on that `TextField` component move that `inputRef={inputRef}` inside `TextField`.
   If you still want to reference `Uf` - try renaming `inputRef` to just `ref`.

---

In other words:
Use `inputRef` with input-type Material-UI components, use `ref` with
regular React Components.

---

4. When it comes to your string length restraint your code should be working fine.

Comment: I think what I wrote over there was a little bit messy to understand, my main goal here is just to limit my Input "UF" and i'm trying to use `inputProps={{ maxLength: 2 }}` but whenever I use it just gives me an error `inputRef.current is null`
and my `<Uf/>` is a exported component that is passing Props to a Material-UI component, so inputRef should be working, i just don't really know if i'm using it correctly and why I need to use it. It's just what the error is telling me

Comment: _"If you want to focus on that TextField component move that inputRef={inputRef} inside TextField"_ this is already being done too, in my Autocomplete on renderInput where TextField is being rendered `{...importedProps}` is where all the props that I define on `<Uf/>` are being deployed

Comment: Try passing that `inputProps={{ maxLength: 2 }}` to TextField then instead of using it in <Uf/>, otherwise idk, what was the point of wrapping that component in another component if it's just going to pass props through itself?

Comment: This + using `...params.inputProps` worked for me, now I just need to figure how to change the input text lol, I'm able to limit the amount of digits and show my desired Value, but I cant type on the input, only use the drop list to change it

Comment: Is it cause you’re using static `value=‘SF’` ? If so i usually fix it by passing a useState to my onChange parameter and having state as value. Not sure if it’s the best practice but it works for me.

Comment: I'll give it a go, but thanks my main issue was solved